# Имеется сетевой диск в предприятии, на котором внезапно исчезло значительное кол-во памяти. Каким ПО можно контролировать такие вещи?

Tags: файлы, администрирование, диск

Хотелось бы такое ПО, что будет следить за тем кто, куда и какие файлы, какого размера скинул, или просто- какого размера.

Comment: Попробуйте "scanner by steffen gerlach" - он наглядно показывает чем занято место на диске.

Comment: Дисковые квоты - отличная вещь...

Comment: @Akina это похоже на ответ. )